# Open multiple webpages, use wget and merge the output

Tags: linux

I have a text file containing a bunch of webpages:

```
http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/7603
http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/5620
…
```

My aim is to download all info on these pages to a single text file.

The following works perfectly but it gives me 3000+ text files, how could I simple merge all the output files during the loop.

```
while read i; do wget $i; done < urls.txt
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-O file` option, which appends the output to the logfile specified.

```
while read i; do wget -O outputFile $i; done < urls.txt
```

The `outputFile` will contain the contents as well

Also you can skip the `while` loop by specifying the input file using `-i file`

```
wget -O outpuFile -i url.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that's all I needed to know!

Comment: You forgot the second "t" in "outputFile" in the last code section.